# CSS flexbox wraps content in FireFox (not Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox, pseudo-element

I have a `button` that consists of an `<i>` and an `<span>` element (an icon and some text). Now both have different sizes so I'm applying a flexbox to my button that should center my items nicely. In Chrome everything works as I expected but using the page in a current FF results in wrapping my inner content of the button. The icon is displayed via a `:before` pseudoelement.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5xp3bd8/)

Who is wrong here? Is it FF or is it Chrome (and me). What should I do to get the same result in either browser (icon before text, vertical center, no wrap)?

Comment: This is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597870/using-display-flex-on-a-button-makes-it-wrap-in-firefox/27627318 -- see my answer over there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27627318/329541

Basically, if you want a button to be a flex container, your best bet is to add a wrapper-<div> inside of the button, and style *that* div as `display:flex`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weird. `button` elements have some special behavior which seems to conflict with flexbox.

Specifically, what happens is that the flex items are blockified, according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> The [`display`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display) value of a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) is [blockified](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-display/#blockify): if
>   the specified [`display`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display) of an in-flow child of an element
>   generating a [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) is an inline-level value, it computes
>   to its block-level equivalent.

Therefore, the `i` and the `span`, which would be `inline`, become `block`s.

However, flex properties do not seem to apply neither to the flex container `button` nor to the flex items `i` and `span`.

So the flex items are displayed according to the block formatting context instead of the flex one, and since they are `block`s, they appear at different lines.

One way to fix it is wrapping the contents in a container, and make it the flex container, instead of the button itself.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
i {
  width: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
i:before {
  content: "\2193";
}
span {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div>
    <i></i>
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

Also consider simplifying the markup.

```css
span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
span:before {
  content: "\2193";
  width: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>Text</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about wrapping the `i` and the `span` into a `div` as well and it might work fine. Anyway I found a way not to use flexbox for this. I just gave the button a `display: table;` and the children `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` This works fine. FYI: I'm using FontAwesome library for my icons so I have to use the `i` element :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify `display: -moz-box;` to works on FF. Check the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5xp3bd8/2/).

Comment: Hi. I'm using Sass with a mixin that should eveluate to `-moz-box` (or `-webkit-flex`, ...) but my FF uses just `flex`. Check out this fiddle that uses both (as my mixin does): https://jsfiddle.net/u5xp3bd8/3/ The problem still exists as FF choses `flex` over `-moz-box`. Btw it works fine when using `-moz-box` explicit.

Comment: Change the order to makes `-moz-box` win: `display: flex; display: -moz-box;`

Comment: Well that works. But I always saw that one should use the standard property as last one after all the fallbacks?!

Comment: Yes. But FF is different. As long I play with css, FF always beat me down and force me to do trick, trick and trick. :D

Comment: Crazy FF. But if that's the only way to go, I'll take it... :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: `display:-moz-box` here actually has no effect -- all it's doing is suppressing the `display:flex` (and its blockification quirk); it doesn't actually get you a flexbox. The suggested `display:flex;display:-moz-box` ends up behaving (in Firefox) as `display` were simply not set.  If you *actually* want the button to be a flexbox, you need to wrap its contents in a wrapper-div and give *that* `display:flex;flex-flow:...;align-items:...;`. As noted above, this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597870/using-display-flex-on-a-button-makes-it-wrap-in-firefox/27627318

Comment: @dholbert: Yes you are right. The `display` property just behaves like it's not set. So the solution by Oriol might be better (or just avoid using flexbox as I pointed out in the comments of the newly accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Applying `flex-shrink: 0` Fixed this issue for me