# Text and image in <button> won't stay on same line using flexbox in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to display a button with an image and text. The text and image must be centered and on the same row/line.

In Firefox the image and text are always on separate lines. How can I solve this?

This is what I've got:

```css
button {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: center;
}

button img {
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

button span {
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr55t9c5/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certain HTML elements, by design, do not accept `display` changes. Three of these elements are:

- `<button>`
- `<fieldset>`
- `<legend>`

For instance, `display: table` won't work on `fieldset`.

Similarly, applying `display: inline-flex` to `button` will be ignored by the browser.

There are other sensible restrictions. For instance, some browsers will ignore `overflow: scroll` on `button` elements. (Tested: Firefox, no scroll; Chrome, yes)

> ***So, bottom line, a `button` element cannot be a flex container.***
>
> ***The easy fix is to wrap the content of the `button` in a `div`, and
>   make the `div` the flex container. Or (as mentioned in the comments) use a `span` instead of a `div`, as this maintains standards compliance.***

**HTML**

```
<button href="#">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10">
        <span>Click me</span>
    </div>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr55t9c5/5/)

NOTE: Although they cannot be flex containers, [`button` elements can be flex items.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33629469/3597276)

Learn more here:

- [Bug 984869 - display: flex doesn't work for button elements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869)
- [Bug 1176786 - Flexbox on a  blockifies the contents but doesn't establish a flex formatting context](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1176786)

Comment: Perfect. Div's inside buttons isn't W3 valid, so I've changed it to a span: https://jsfiddle.net/tr55t9c5/6/ - Also, I see there are other solutions, but in my case i really needed the flex-box feature to more easily control the height of the button.

Answer (score -1):

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/tr55t9c5/3/

remove all the css and just add this css only.

```
    button {text-align:center;}
```