# Flex item with 0% basis overflows on IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, flexbox

As can be seen in this simple codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mazjyv, there's a button which is a flex item with a `flex-basis` of `0%`.

In other browsers content does not overflow the button container, however on IE11 it does.

Any clue why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this rule:

```
button
{
    flex: 0 0 0%;
}
```

You're telling the `button`: *don't grow*, *don't shrink*, *your initial main size is 0*.

Instead use:

```
button
{
    flex: 1 0 0%;
}
```

Also, btw, the text overflow was also happening in Chrome 46.

Comment: The problem with that is it grows too much. In Canary and Firefox it behaves like I want: doesn't grow or shrink and collapses the 2 words on 2 lines.

Comment: By "the 2 words" I mean the words inside the button container are placed one on each line.

Comment: Do you want the words on two lines at all times?

Comment: Nope, that's the thing. I want it to collapse one when there just isn't enough space.

Comment: Buttons can't be flex containers though.

Comment: Also, as far as I know the flex spec says that unless clearly specified using widths or heights, flex item's contents should never overflow their container. That is, a `flex-basis` of `0`, would translate to content-width or content-height. Maybe this is fixed in Canary which is why it works there, but not totally sure about this.

Comment: Actually, I just remembered, `<button>` elements don't recognize flex properties: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33345537/3597276

Comment: Buttons can't be flex containers, but they can be flex items if I remember right. The button in the codepen works well with `flex` as long as it doesn't have a 0-basis.

Comment: Here's why: given this iamge from the Flexbox spec http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/images/rel-vs-abs-flex.svg it clear that I need to set a basis of `auto` so that non-content spacing doesn't grow or shrink. Then, in order to get the words to collapse, I should set a `max-width`.

Comment: Another option is to set the basis to `0%` and set a `min-width`. I think I like this one better.

Comment: Thank you for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Quick note on your answer update: flex properties do apply to button elements, just not flex container ones. Flex item properties are fine.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct. I've rolled back the edit and [revised my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33345537/3597276). Thanks.