# How can i make this button and Icon aligned? they are off

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML for the section i am working on...

```
<div id="projects">
   <H1 class="projects">PROJECTS</H1>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <button class="leftbtn"></button>
   <button class="rightbtn"></button>
</div>
```

and here is the css...

```
#projects {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #306e73;
    margin-top: 100px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.projects {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: center;
}

.box {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    background-color: #848181;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.leftbtn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.leftbtn:before {
    content: "\f137";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: #ff5335;
    font-size: 70px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -8px;
    }

    .rightbtn {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        margin-top: -150px;
        border-radius: 100px;
    }

    .rightbtn:before {
        content: "\f138";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        color: #ff5335;
        font-size: 70px;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: -8px;
    }
```

The left and right button are not aligned with the icons. I cant seem to figure out how to get them to align! ha please help me from going crazy :)

Comment: What do you mean by align(vertically or horizontally)?

Comment: I just fixed it a little bit. so now i guess vertically

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34235428/3597276 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/33345537/3597276

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyv263q9/ here's a fiddle for your issue, I fixed one button, try the other the same way. Your css is a bit jumbled up, it seems

Comment: That worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desire situation by `position:absolute;`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/yw551yLz/)

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP told try using `position:absolute`in the leftbtn before and rightbtn before

```
 .rightbtn:before {
    content: "\f138";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: #ff5335;
    font-size: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/xbesr5u4/)

Thanks