# Input controls overflowing flex container in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I'm having issues on Firefox (fine in Chrome) with a flexbox input group - the select input is pushing the text input out of the container.

I've extracted some of the markup and replicated the relevant styling below:

```css
.column.names {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
select {
  min-width: 6em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 7em;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
.input_group {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='column names'>

  <div>
    <label for="user_name">Name</label>
    <div>
      <div class='input_group'>
        <select name="user[title]" id="user_title">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option selected="selected" value="Mr">Mr</option>
          <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <input maxlength="255" size="255" type="text" name="user[name]" id="user_name" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="user_company">Company</label>
    <div>
      <input maxlength="255" size="255" type="text" value="" name="user[company]" id="user_company" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j9s0fk8c/

To clarify, the Name select + input box combined should be the same width as the Company input box.

Again this has been fine in Chrome but for some reason flexbox is giving us no end of issues in Firefox (this is just one in a long line of weird issues we've had to deal with)

Comment: I just checked the given JSFiddle with Firefox and it looks fine to me. What is your Firefox version?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in firefox.

Comment: For anyone running into this issue for another reason, the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43361500/2873507

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding a border around the flex container, the problem can be seen in Firefox:

[**DEMO 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/j9s0fk8c/3/)

It appears that the primary reason for the overflow is the `size` attribute in the `input` elements.

```
<input class="string optional form-control group_item" maxlength="255" size="255"
      type="text" name="user[name]" id="user_name" />
```

The `size="255"` is setting the size of the control which, depending on the browser, may conflict with the size you set in the CSS. By removing this attribute and letting CSS manage the width, the problem seems to be resolved:

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/j9s0fk8c/5/)

Note that the `size` attribute controls only the size of the `input`. It does not affect the number of characters you can enter, which is controlled by the `maxlength` attribute (also present in your code).

For example:

```
<input type="text" size="5" maxlength="20" >
```

In the code above, the control will be five characters in width (unless overridden by CSS), but can accept up to 20 characters.

More details on the `size` and `maxlength` attributes can be found here: [MDN `<input>` definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks, I think I was focusing too much on CSS and assumed it was one of several Firefox flexbox bugs as I've just got to the bottom of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597870/using-display-flex-on-a-button-makes-it-wrap-in-firefox

Comment: BTW, in the demos above, Chrome overflows as well if you get rid of `width:100%` from the inputs. Chrome seems to be treating that percent-width as clamping the width to a greater extent than it actually should. I filed https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=785041 on this.

Comment: Note that in addition to the solution above the default size attribute on an input field is 20. You can specify the width to 1 (this will only be a default and be overridden by the CSS"

example:

<input type="text">
this input has a default size of 20 and could affect the width of the input field.

Comment: Another solution is to set `min-width` to 0 in the CSS.

Answer (score 10):

Try using "min-width: 0" for inputbox. T
This generally happens in Mozilla when using flex. Try using "min-width: 0" for input box.

Comment: this fixed the problem for me ! thanks for sharing the answer, I would have never thought of that, and still have no clue why it worked.

Comment: This fixed the same issue for me, any idea why that is?