# Strange input widths in Firefox vs. Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've got some number inputs in a flex layout which are not sizing as expected in Firefox, and I don't understand why.

The result in Chrome:
[image: chrome output]

The result in Firefox:
[image: firefox output]

As you can see, the XP row doesn't overflow its parent in Chrome (no horizontal scrolling), but it has *significant* overflow in Firefox (with horizontal scrolling), on top of the number inputs overlapping neighboring label texts.

The relevant HTML & CSS from the page is:

```css
/**
 * The ".charsheet" prefix on each rule is automatically added
 */
.charsheet .sheet-flexbox-h input[type=number] {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.charsheet .sheet-flexbox-inline > label > span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 89%;
}

.charsheet .sheet-flexbox-h > label {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.charsheet .sheet-flexbox-inline {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.charsheet .sheet-3colrow .sheet-2col:last-child {
    width: calc(66% - 5px);
}

.charsheet .sheet-body {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.charsheet .sheet-content {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.charsheet {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
}

/**
 * CSS rules below are on the page, but not editable by me
 */
.ui-dialog .charsheet input[type=number] {
    width: 3.5em;
}

.ui-dialog .charsheet input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!-- I can only modify the descendants of .charsheet -->
<div class="charsheet tab-pane lang-en" style="display: block;">
    <div class="sheet-content">
        <div class="sheet-body">
            <!-- ... -->
            <div class="sheet-3colrow">
                <div class="sheet-col"><!-- ... --></div>
                <div class="sheet-2col">
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <div class="sheet-flexbox-h sheet-flexbox-inline">
                        <label>
                            <span data-i18n="current-experience-points">Current XP:</span>
                            <input type="number" name="attr_xp">
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <span data-i18n="total-experience-points">Total XP:</span>
                            <input type="number" name="attr_xp_max">
                        </label>
                        <!-- etc... -->
                    </div><!-- /sheet-flexbox-h -->
                    <!-- ... -->
                </div><!-- /sheet-2col -->
            </div><!-- /sheet-3colrow -->
            <!-- ... -->
        </div><!-- /sheet-body -->
        <div class="sheet-footer"><!-- ... --></div>
    </div><!-- /sheet-content -->
</div><!-- /charsheet -->
```

My *full* CSS and HTML can be found at [Roll20/roll20-character-sheets on GitHub](https://github.com/Roll20/roll20-character-sheets/tree/master/Exalted%203). The full CSS that I can't edit can be found live (minified) at [Roll20.net](https://app.roll20.net/assets/app.css)

**Update:** I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Lithl/az1njzn8/

[Fiddle in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZHpd.jpg), [fiddle in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrtH6.jpg)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Short answer

Add a simple `min-width:0` rule to the `input` selector

#### Explanation

After doing a bit of research, I think the conclusion that I can make here is that `flex` has been known to have various issues and different behaviours across browsers, specially Firefox. I found a couple of useful threads that can lead to various fixes/hacks to have consistent results. A thread that helped me is : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/firefox-flexbox-not-working (scroll down to the comments)

Coming back to your question, I was able to fix it using two separate ways and I was able to produce consistent results in Chrome and Firefox. Both of them require a simple CSS change.

#### First approach

Change your CSS to the following:

```
.charsheet .sheet-flexbox-h input[type=text],
.charsheet .sheet-flexbox-h input[type=number],
.charsheet .sheet-flexbox-h select {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

I noticed that you had 40% as the `flex-basis` value but could not really figure out why you had this value, perhaps it may have other impacts elsewhere changing it to `auto`. But this does fix the issue.

#### Second approach

Add a simple `min-width:0` rule to the `input` selector in your CSS. So your CSS would look like:

```
.charsheet input[type=text],
.charsheet input[type=number] {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width:0;
  width: 165px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

I found this helpful tip from the link I posted above. Again, I do not have a very concrete explanation as to why this works, but it seems to get the job done.

I would recommend you go with the second approach, as it may have minimal impact since you are setting the width.

Working fiddle here with second approach: https://jsfiddle.net/az1njzn8/4/

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with number inputs behaving differently in Chrome vs. Firefox, and Gurtej's solution unfortunately didn't work for me.

What works for me though is to set a default width that would override the useragent's default width – even though the width is eventually being modified by more complex rules and circumstances with percentages, min-width, max-width and flexbox.

```
input[type="number"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Compare https://jsfiddle.net/pyu0h1r2/1/ vs. https://jsfiddle.net/pyu0h1r2/2/.